# gdb watchpoint not triggering on memory address

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently, I tried to debug a memory corruption bug using `gdb`'s [`watchpoint`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) feature on a memory address which falsely got overwritten by some piece of code.

Surprisingly, this did not work. I ended up fixing my problem but without `gdb`'s help. Here is a small code example which demonstrates how the `watchpoint` does not trigger:

```
void main() {
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78
    };

    data[4] = 0x89;
}
```

This code declares an array with size 4 and writes to the 4th index. Oops, we corrupted a byte of memory.

Using `gdb`, I acquired the address of `data[4]` before the assignment was executed and set a `watchpoint` on the address:

```
(gdb) p/x &data[4]
$1 = 0x7ffffffee950
(gdb) watch *0x7ffffffee950
Hardware watchpoint 2: *0x7ffffffee950
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 14543) exited normally]
```

As you can see, the application continues as normal and exits. No reaction from `gdb`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here? I would expect to get something from `gdb` if the address is modified but nothing happens.

My version of gdb is:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Array size is 4. So last index is 3. Are you trying to change the value of data[3] ?

Comment: Hmm, why did you set a watchpoint outside of the bounds of the array ? I am not sure of the behavior of `gdb` when you have this kind of request. And, memcheck (valgrind) would probably be more meaningful to track this kind of bug.

Comment: @perror This is the part where you get stack smashing.

Comment: You've got undefined behaviour upon undefined. What makes you think this does do anything like that?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Check what [Valgrind says about that](https://pastebin.com/raw/3JdFxFQV).  See - [TESTED](https://ideone.com/fmS4nH) Code.

Comment: Why are people downvoting if they can't understand a simple question? `valgrind` reports nothing though: `/usr/bin/valgrind --tool=memcheck --xml=yes --xml-file=/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/valgrind --gen-suppressions=all --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=yes --read-var-info=yes --read-inline-info=yes /mnt/d/my-project/cmake-build-debug/my-project
==14911== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block`
(I'm using the CLion IDE integration of `valgrind`)

Comment: Since `data[4]` does not exist, you have undefined behavior in your program. Then it seems logical that gdb cannot debug undefined behavior, or here, handle a watch point of an undefined variable.

Comment: Try `set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0` before setting the watchpoint. Maybe WSL has problems with hardware watchpoints.

Comment: [gdb watch point doesn't work - WSL issue #2609](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2609)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, this seems to be linked to the fact that your example lies in the `main()` function. I tried with the following example:

```
void foo() {
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78
    };
    data[4] = 0x89;
}

void main() {
  foo();
}
```

I compiled it and ran `gdb` on it:

```
$> gcc -g3 -fno-stack-protector -o sample sample.c
$> gdb -q ./sample
Reading symbols from ./sample...done.
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1129: file sample.c, line 2.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/sample 

Breakpoint 1, foo () at sample.c:2
2       unsigned char data[] = {
(gdb) p /x &data[4]
$1 = 0x7fffffffe150
(gdb) watch *0x7fffffffe150
Hardware watchpoint 2: *0x7fffffffe150
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: *0x7fffffffe150

Old value = -7840
New value = -7799
foo () at sample.c:7
7
```

So, it seems to work fine in `foo()` (but, I can also say it won't work in `main()`). I will take a look why...

### EDIT

It seems I had a glitch (or I did something different but I cannot remember what). It works perfectly on my system (Debian unstable with gdb 8.1). Here is the code I used:

```
void main() {
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78
    };
    data[4] = 0x89;
}
```

Compiling and running `gdb` on it:

```
$> gcc -Wall -Wextra -fno-stack-protector -g3 -o sample sample.c
$> gdb -q ./sample
Reading symbols from ./sample...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1129: file sample.c, line 2.
Starting program: /tmp/sample 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at sample.c:2
2       unsigned char data[] = {
(gdb) p /x &data[4]
$1 = 0x7fffffffe160
(gdb) watch *0x7fffffffe160
Hardware watchpoint 2: *0x7fffffffe160
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: *0x7fffffffe160

Old value = 1431654720
New value = 1431654793
main () at sample.c:6
6   }
```

Nothing strange... The watchpoint worked as expected. But, this is strange because it did not work at first... I might have done something slightly different... Maybe, I did put the watchpoint before starting the program. It might have some role in this.

Comment: This code  compiles with `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated`. Why `seems to work fine` ?

Comment: Use the option `-fno-stack-protector` to remove the stack-smashing protection (this is not the default on my system).

Comment: Accessing memory which does not belongs to you or your program should be `valgrind`  job, isn't it?

Comment: All this memory belongs to your program anyway. It won't segfault.

Comment: `UB` means that the program can behave as expected and also that is possible that your System give you rights to access/write that memory location.